# An old data is keeped in my Android Sqlite database

Tags: android, sqlite

I'm doing update of my app, the goals of this, is to send data trough a SOAP service, my idea is to drop table at each app update, or uninstallation and reinstallation, so I did this:

```
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 2;
private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "name.db";
private static final String TABLE_DEMANDES = "demandes";
private static final String KEY_ID = "id";
private static final String KEY_XML = "xml";
private static final String KEY_STATUTENVOIE = "statutEnvoie";
private static final String KEY_DATEENVOIE = "dateEnvoie";

public DatabaseHandler(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
}


@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_DEMANDES);
    String CREATE_DEMANDES_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_DEMANDES + "(" + KEY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," + KEY_XML + " TEXT," + KEY_STATUTENVOIE + " INTEGER," + KEY_DATEENVOIE + " DATETIME" + ")";
    db.execSQL(CREATE_DEMANDES_TABLE);
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    onCreate(db);
}
```

But when my SOAP service do a loop on my database and look at the data not sent, I found an old data, but I don't understand why because I delete table at onCreate, so why I get back this data ? I reinstalled my app.

UPDATE:

```
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 3;
private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "name.db";
private static String DB_NAME = "Solutis";
private static final String TABLE_DEMANDES = "demandes";
private static final String KEY_ID = "id";
private static final String KEY_XML = "xml";
private static final String KEY_STATUTENVOIE = "statutEnvoie";
private static final String KEY_DATEENVOIE = "dateEnvoie";

public DatabaseHandler(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
}


@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    String CREATE_DEMANDES_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_DEMANDES + "(" + KEY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," + KEY_XML + " TEXT," + KEY_STATUTENVOIE + " INTEGER," + KEY_DATEENVOIE + " DATETIME" + ")";
    db.execSQL(CREATE_DEMANDES_TABLE);
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_DEMANDES);
    onCreate(db);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget to increment DB version number.

And move `db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_DEMANDES);` in `onUpgrade` method (so it's a bit cleaner).

Check documentation about [onCreate()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteOpenHelper.html#onCreate(android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase)) and [onUpgrade()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteOpenHelper.html#onUpgrade(android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase,%20int,%20int)).

You can trace what's happening with logging:

```
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    Log.i("MYDB", "onCreate " + DATABASE_VERSION);
...
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    Log.i("MYDB", "onUpgrade: old " + oldVersion + " new " + newVersion);
```

Try freshly installed app first. Then increment DB version, upload and test again.

Comment: If I drop the table in the onCreate and I call the onCreate in onUpgrade I don't understand where is the error, if I drop the table in the 2 use cases

Comment: Do not drop table in onCreate, do it only in onUpgrade. Every time you want  to upgrade increment version number.

Comment: Nice but I have a really hard problem, it's more difficult: I have 2 rows for exemple the first is an incremental number (id) and the second is the uuid to recognize each user installation. My problem is to don't have collision of same uuid and incremental number, I have to change the uuid and reload my database if the user do an update or an reinstallation.

Comment: Use onCreate and onUpgrade for creation and update your scheme. To modify content use [SQLiteDatabase](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html) methods update or insert.

Comment: Okay what about on a app update, does the app delete the data or it's only on a uninstallation case ?

Comment: It depends on code, you can drop your table anytime. Android OS guaranties to call some callbacks. Check documentation and play a bit with logging.

Answer (score 0):

`onCreate()` is called when you got not database at all (so on fresh installation). When you install update **and** database version is different, then `onUpdate()` is called to let you, well, update the database. If you want fresh install regardless it's update or not, you need to drop your database in `onUpdate()` as well.

See [SQLOpenHelper docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteOpenHelper.html) for details.

**EDIT**

`onUpdate()` is called **only** on DB version change, **NOT** on application update. Therefore you must bump your `DATABASE_VERSION` in each app update if you want SQLOpenHelper to come into play each time.

Comment: If I drop the table in the onCreate and I call the onCreate in onUpgrade I don't understand where is the error, if I drop the table in the 2 use cases

Comment: Okay I updated my question, but you're saying that onUpgrade will be called by changing the version, but if the user uninstall the app I will loose the data too ?

Comment: If user uninstall your app manually then there will no DB to update because old database is removed on unsintall too. And in such case new installation will be fresh one with `onCreate()` called.

Comment: I did a test, on app update the database keep the data